# How to repair a rosbag file download missing some parts

Tags: ros, rosbag, ros-kinetic, download

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a big size (few gigas) rosbag file , I download earlier, and then find out it is missing some info like the image ( form rqt_bag) shows:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Jmm5eyapBoLmyJV03sFDtlp-8S3KHHUK

the problem is my Internet connection will take (forever) time to download it form start ,

**Is there any way to download only the missing parts?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299156/how-to-repair-a-rosbag-file-download-missing-some-parts/) by [engyasin](https://answers.ros.org/users/36088/engyasin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Missing parts within a file is never a problem with modern download tools (wget, web browsers, etc). They all use multiple levels of checksums and hashes to ensure that files are downloaded correctly.

The ROS bag format also includes internal checksums that and you would be unable to open the bag file at all if part of it was missing.

In your case, it actually looks like there we no messages published on those topics for a short period of time. `rqt_bag` draws a vertical blue line on each topic for each message that is published. For most bag files these lines blend together, but in some cases you can see gaps where the publisher did not send any messages (or where messages were dropped because the bag recorder was overloaded).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [engyasin](https://answers.ros.org/users/36088/engyasin/) on 2018-07-31**:
ok , that's interesting,  I like the recorder overloading theory, because the camera always send images (why stop in the middle?), I will contact the the people that set these rosbag to make sure, .. if the error from rosbag downlaod , I will leave the question unanswered